# Performing Functions in MySQL vs. PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I just learned that you can perform loops and things like that directly in MySQL rather than using PHP for them.  Which is more efficient hardware-wise?  When would it be advantageous to use each over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on details of your architecture and application, such as how much data would be returned from the DB in either form, and the latency between the database server and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a case of horses for courses. Generally the efficiency of PLSQL is TERRIBLE when compared to the efficiency of a programming language - but if the difference is that you can run one very simple statement in a database and return 100 rows of data, versus returning a million rows of data and processing them all code to get to the same 100 rows... well you see where this is heading.

Generally speaking, it comes down to experience - but most of all it comes down to testing it out for yourself. If you have a long job that you think might be better done in another part of the code, or in another system - write it and test it. See what works better. There simply isn't a "one shoe fits all" answer for this.